# Is Android in-app purchase availability limited based on the developer's region?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment, in-app-billing

Is android in-app purchase availability limited based on the developer's region? If yes, does Google publishes a list of countries where developers can use in-app purchase in their apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is limited and google publishes a list

Using the link below, you can find app availability information, along with supported currency and price range information for Google Play users.

See [this page for supported countries](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286?hl=en)